# google-drive-api method "drive.files.create" stopped working (V3 - 1.58.0.2859) and return nothing

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api

We have a **.Net** app using Google Drive api to upload files to a g-drive. And it just stopped working days ago (Nov 29th). But we didn't remember doing anything changes during that time.

During the investigation, we could confirm the service account for calling the Google API are valid, since the same service account is also being used for calling other google APIs, and works fine. We also can confirm it's not a permission issue, since we even set the permission of the gdrive to allow "anyone" who has the link, to have edit permission, but the issue is still there.

Unfortunately, we cannot find any useful log, and the return message of the API call is `NULL`. No error code or error message returned.The only related info we saw is:  on the chart of "Error by API method", it shows "drive.files.create" failed 100%.

One interesting thing is, if we disable the Google Drive API, then enable it again, it will work once, then will stop working again.

```java
private string SaveFileToGoogleDrive(IFormFile file, string claimNumber)
        {
            try
            {
                var driveService = GetDriveServiceInstance();
                var fileMetadata = new Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File();
                var mimeType = file.ContentType;
                fileMetadata.Name = CreateFileName(file.FileName, claimNumber);
                fileMetadata.MimeType = mimeType;
                fileMetadata.Parents = new List { _googleSettings.GoogleDriveFolderId };
                FilesResource.CreateMediaUpload request;
                using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    file.CopyTo(stream);
                    request = driveService.Files.Create(fileMetadata, stream, mimeType);
                    request.Fields = "id";
                    request.Upload();
                }
                var googleFile = request.ResponseBody; \\The response body is always NULL, after the issue happened. :(
                return googleFile.Id;
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                _logger.Error($"Google Drive exception {ex.Message} SACKTRACE: {(ex.StackTrace ?? "")} INNER EXCEPTION: {(ex.InnerException != null ? ex.InnerException.Message + "STACK TRACE:" + ex.InnerException.StackTrace ?? "" : "")}");
                return string.Empty;
            }
        }
```

[image: screenshot - the only error showing on the chart]

We found more details from the progress property in the response object, and saw the error message "The user's Drive storage quota has been exceeded.", but it does not make sense at all, since we are using "Enterprise edition" Google Workspace, which is supposed to have no limit. The service account and the key look good, GCP didn't complain at all. And that's the first thing we checked during troubleshooting.

Do you have any idea on what to do to solve the issue or what too look for when investigating this issue?

Comment: Please edit your question and include an error message, how do you know its not working exactly?  Your going to have to add more debugging on your end.  It could be anything, timeout, out of space.   I would be leaning to out of space since recreating it fixes it until you run out of space again.   try adding an about.get from the service account and see how much space it has left.

Comment: Thank U, Like I mentioned in my original post, other than the only evidence showing in the dashboard -"drive.files.create" failed, there is no error be logged, which is odd.

Answer (score 0):

We found more details from the progress property in the response object, and saw the error message "The user's Drive storage quota has been exceeded.", but it's not make sense at all, since we are using "Enterprise editions" google workspace, which suppose has no limit. The service account and key look good, GCP didn't complain any thing. And that's the first thing we checked during troubleshooting. Anyway, the fix is: after create a new service account then use the new key of this new service account, the system back to work.